# validity of proof $\pi$ is irrational from Euler's product formula

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, irrational-numbers, pi, euler-product

Many articles and blog posts (and some textbooks) mention in passing that Euler's product formula can be used to prove that $\pi$ is irrational.

$$ \zeta(s) = \sum_n \frac{1}{n^s} = \prod_n \left( \frac{1}{1-p^{-s}} \right) $$

Taking $s=2$ gives us the Basel proble, and so:

$$ \frac{\pi^2}{6} =\prod_n \left( \frac{1}{1-p^{-2}} \right) $$

Since we know that there are infinite primes, and that each factor in the product is finite, we can say that $\pi$ can't be written as a product of finite rationals.

**Is this correct?**

This is the explanation given in several sources, but my concern is that **we also need to show the infinite product can't be reduced**, for example by "telescoping".

I would appreciate replies that were suitable for readers without university maths training.

Comment: _Usually_, this reasoning goes the other way: Because we know $\pi^2$ is irrational, and because we know each factor in the product is rational, there must be infinitely many terms, and therefore there are infinitely many primes.

Comment: I share @Arthur's suspicion. One can also prove there are infinitely many primes by noting $\zeta(1)$ diverges.

Comment: What did you mean by " and that each factor in the product is finite "

Comment: @AderinsolaJoshua that $(1-1/p^2)^{-1}$ is finite for all $p$. I should also have said finite and non-zero.

Comment: hi @Arthur thanks, that is helpful. Can the reasoning be done this way around, starting from the infinitude of primes (we can use $\zeta(1)$ to do that) and then show that the infinite product can't be reduced, and so $\pi^2$$ is irrational? What would be have to show about the infinite product to do this?

Answer (score 1):

**No**. Infinitely many positive rationals can have a positive rational product. For example, $\prod_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1-(k+2)^{-2}}{1-(k+1)^{-2}}$ telescopes to $\tfrac43$, which is an example of the concern you raise.

Comment: Another example (although extremely trivial): $\prod_{k=1}^\infty1$.

Comment: @j-g so can we show that in this case that $\prod_n \left( \frac{1}{1-p^{-2}} \right)$ can't be reduced?

Comment: @TariqRashid What might help, though I've found no theorem that would make this trivial, is to show the partial products converge so rapidly their limit can't be rational. ([Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number#Liouville_numbers_and_transcendence) is a theorem that constrains how well algebraic numbers can be approximated by rational numbers of small denominator, but I'm not sure any similar result for products would be of use here.)